# Confused about Ruby on Rails routes.rb syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I had the following code in my routes.rb file.

```
  get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard'
```

I know what's going on (a public url being mapped to a specific controller/view file which will process and return the request). That is not what I am confused about.

As a Ruby beginner, I'm confused about what Ruby code convention this is. It doesn't look like the correct way to declare a variable or call a method? What exactly is going on and is this some sort of shorthand form to call a method?

```
get("/dashboard", "dashboard#index", "dashboard")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common way to allow *options* to be passed to a method. Like the following:

```
def do_something(subject, options = {})
  subject.perform_something
  subject.perform_caching if options[:cache]
  subject.send_report unless options[:skip_reporting]
  # etc.
end
```

So you can call:

```
something(some_object)
something(some_object, cache: true)
something(some_object, skip_reporting: true, cache: true)
```

You can even set up defaults, like this:

```
def do_something_else(subject, options = {})
  options = { cache: true, skip_reporting: false }.merge(options)
  subject.perform_something
  subject.perform_caching if options[:cache]
  subject.send_report unless options[:skip_reporting]
end
```

So that by default if no `cache` options if given, it will be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

Yes, `get` is a method that is being called. In ruby, you can omit the parentheses. So,

```
get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard'
```

Is the same as:

```
get("/dashboard", to: "dashboard#index", :as => "dashboard")
```

Where `to:` and `:as` are named parameters which are received by `get` as a `hash`.

I *think* this method is defined in `action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb`:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class Mapper

      module HttpHelpers
        # Define a route that only recognizes HTTP GET.
        # For supported arguments, see match[rdoc-ref:Base#match]
        #
        #   get 'bacon', to: 'food#bacon'
        def get(*args, &block)
          map_method(:get, args, &block)
        end
        ...
      end

    end
  end
end
```

So, you can see that `to: "dashboard#index", :as => "dashboard"` are received by `*args` and the `splat operator` allows for a variable length set of arguments.

Comment: So "to:" is just the name of a parameter (to be explicit) of the "get" method? I recognize the second part, which is just a key-value pair for a hash.

Comment: I don't think the `to` is optional for a `get`... I mean I don't know how Rails could guess where to map `/dashboard` to some controller & action, right?

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Yeah, I was just looking at the `action_dispatch` source code 'cause I was feeling a little uncomfortable with my `optional` assertion. I think I'll remove that word as it feels imprecise.

Comment: Yeah just tested it, you cannot just use `get '/somewhere'`, you have to pass a `:to` or a `:action` key/value (maybe others)

Comment: Out of curiosity, to you get a `Wrong number of arguments` error? Or, does it barf for other reasons?

Comment: Yes. Both `to: "dashboard#index"` and `:as => "dashboard"` are simply key-value pairs. In general, I believe `key: value` is preferred over `:key => value`, although I find that in some instances, rails is finicky (or at least it seems finicky to me but I may be munging things up) and requires the `:key => value` format.

Comment: The only place I can think of that would require the `key => value` syntax would be if you want the key to be a string or any object that isn't a Symbol, so `SomeClass => 'some value'` or `'some string key' => 'some value'`

Comment: Actually, the only place I've *seemed* to experience any weirdness is in `routes.rb` when I do `only: [:index, :show, ...]`. It seemed like it wasn't processing the directive correctly. But, if I did `:only => [:index, :show, ...]`, all was good. Like I said, I may have mucked something up somewhere.

Comment: @jvillian: This makes no sense. Like almost all programming languages, Ruby does not allow libraries to change the fundamental syntax of the language. Rails *cannot possibly be finicky* about syntax, because Rais *cannot possibly know* about syntax. All the method knows is that it receives a `Hash` object as an argument. *How* that object was constructed, and which syntax was used to construct it, is something that it simply cannot possibly know. In fact, the difference between old-style and new-style symbolkey-value syntax is handled strictly by the parser, so *not even the interpreter* knows

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thank you for the very thoughtful and illuminating comment! As a self-taught programmer, it is very helpful to be reminded of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

```
get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard'
```

This is just a normal *message send* (what you call a "method call", but note that messages and methods are different things in Ruby, and the metaphor of sending a message is really important).

In Ruby, you are allowed to leave out the parentheses around an argument list. So, this is the same as this:

```
get('/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard')
```

You are also allowed to leave out the receiver of the message send, in which case it is implied to be `self`, so this is the same as this:

```
self.get('/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard')
```

If the last argument to a message send is a `Hash` literal, you are allowed to leave out the curly braces, so this is the same as this:

```
self.get('/dashboard', { to: 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard' })
```

If the key in a `Hash` literal is a `Symbol`, you are allowed to write `key: value` instead of `:key => value`, so this is the same as this:

```
self.get('/dashboard', { :to => 'dashboard#index', :as => 'dashboard' })
```

Now, doesn't that look just like a boring old message send?

Most of these rules are there to allow you to write code that looks more natural. For example, things that *would* be keywords in other languages, are just methods in Ruby, like `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor`, `require`, `private`, `public`, `protected`, etc. It would look weird, if you were required to use parentheses and receivers there:

```
self.protected()
def foo() end
# instead of
protected
def foo() end

# or

self.private(def foo() end)
# instead of
private def foo() end
```

The rule that you can leave out the curly braces around a trailing `Hash` literal was introduced, so that you could "fake" keyword arguments:

```
def route(path, options = {}) end
route(:index, :from => :here, :to => :there)
```

Even more so with the new-style symbol keys:

```
route(:index, from: :here, to: :there)
```

Note that as of Ruby 2.0, Ruby also has *proper* keyword arguments, which for backwards-compatibility look *exactly* like a trailing `Hash`:

```
def route(path, from:, to:, with: nil) end
route(:index, from: :here, to: :there) # this line same as above
```